# Baffling error using dataprep function in R Synth package

Tags: r

I am trying to use the 'Synth' package in R to explore the effect that certain coups had on economic growth in the countries where they occurred, but I'm hung up on an error I can't understand. When I attempt to run `dataprep()`, I get the following:

```
Error in dataprep(foo = World, predictors = c("rgdpe.pc", "population.ln",  : 

 unit.variable not found as numeric variable in foo.
```

That's puzzling because my data frame, `World`, does include a numeric id called "idno" as specified in the call to `dataprep()`.

Here is the script I'm using. It ingests a .csv with the requisite data from GitHub. The final step --- the call to `dataprep()` --- is where the error arises. I would appreciate help in figuring out why this error arises and how to avoid it so I can get on to the `synth()` part to follow.

```
library(dplyr)
library(Synth)

# DATA INGESTION AND TRANSFORMATION

World <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulfelder/coups-and-growth/master/data.raw.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

World$rgdpe.pc = World$rgdpe/World$pop # create per capita version of GDP (PPP)
World$idno = as.numeric(as.factor(World$country))  # create numeric country id
World$population.ln = log(World$population/1000)  # population size in 1000s, logged
World$trade.ln = log(World$trade)  # trade as % of GDP, logged
World$civtot.ln = log1p(World$civtot)  # civil conflict scale, +1 and logged
World$durable.ln = log1p(World$durable)  # political stability, +1 and logged
World$polscore = with(World, ifelse(polity >= -10, polity, NA)) # create version of Polity score that's missing for -66, -77, and -88
World <- World %>%  # create clocks counting years since last coup (attempt) or 1950, whichever is most recent
    arrange(countrycode, year) %>%
    mutate(cpt.succ.d = ifelse(cpt.succ.n > 0, 1, 0),
           cpt.any.d = ifelse(cpt.succ.n > 0 | cpt.fail.n > 0, 1, 0)) %>%
    group_by(countrycode, idx = cumsum(cpt.succ.d == 1L)) %>%
    mutate(cpt.succ.clock = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-idx) %>%
    group_by(countrycode, idx = cumsum(cpt.any.d == 1L)) %>%
    mutate(cpt.any.clock = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-idx) %>%
    mutate(cpt.succ.clock.ln = log1p(cpt.succ.clock), # include +1 log versions
           cpt.any.clock.ln = log1p(cpt.any.clock))

# THAILAND 2006

THI.coup.year = 2006

THI.years = seq(THI.coup.year - 5, THI.coup.year + 5)
# Get names of countries that had no coup attempts during window analysis will cover. If you wanted to restrict the comparison to a
# specific region or in any other categorical way, this would be the place to do that as well.
THI.controls <- World %>%
    filter(year >= min(THI.years) & year <= max(THI.years)) %>% # filter to desired years
    group_by(idno) %>%  # organize by country
    summarise(coup.ever = sum(cpt.any.d)) %>%  # get counts by country of years with coup attempts during that period
    filter(coup.ever==0) %>%  # keep only the ones with 0 counts
    select(idno)  # cut down to country names
THI.controls = unlist(THI.controls)  # convert that data frame to a vector
names(THI.controls) = NULL  # strip the vector of names

THI.synth.dat <- dataprep(

    foo = World,

    predictors = c("rgdpe.pc", "population.ln", "trade.ln", "fcf", "govfce", "energy.gni", "polscore", "durable.ln", "cpt.any.clock.ln", "civtot.ln"),
    predictors.op = "mean",
    time.predictors.prior = seq(from = min(THI.years), to = THI.coup.year - 1),

    dependent = "rgdpe.pc",

    unit.variable = "idno",
    unit.names.variable = "country",
    time.variable = "year",

    treatment.identifier = unique(World$idno[World$country=="Thailand"]),
    controls.identifier = THI.controls,

    time.optimize.ssr = seq(from = THI.coup.year, to = max(THI.years)),
    time.plot = THI.years

)
```

Comment: Hi @ulfelder, have you succeeded in adjusting your code? Do you mind to share the final one in your question as EDIT or at least the part where you would plot the difference? I figured out `dataprep` but not sure how to plot it. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Googme, the code that worked is in a public GitHub repo: https://github.com/ulfelder/coups-and-growth

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

Your `dplyr` statement:

```
World <- World %>% ...
```

converts `World` from a `data.frame` to a `tbl_df` object (read the docs on `dplyr`). Unfortunately, this causes `mode(World[,"idno"])` to return `list`, not `numeric` and the test for numeric `unit.variable` fails.

You can fix this by using

```
`World <- as.data.frame(World)`
```

just before the call to `dataprep(...)`.

Unfortunately (again) you now get a different error which may be due to the logic of your dplyr statement.

Comment: Got it. I think the new error has to do with the fact that not all of the countries included in the `controls.identifier=` bit are observed for all of the years covered by `THI.years`. I'll do some filtering on that criterion in the process that produces `THI.controls` and see if that resolves the problem. In any case, thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I've now gotten `dataprep()` to run. It requires a lot of preprocessing of the data to make sure that the data frame passed to `foo` includes only balanced panels with enough non-NA values for all cases in both the pre-treatment and post-treatment years to generate the requisite statistics. That's not necessarily a bad thing, but it wasn't clear from the documentation and paper on 'Synth'.