# `write.dbf` fails with an object of class `tbl_df`

Tags: r, dplyr

I do a lot of my work with `.dbf` files, and also with `dplyr`. There's a bug in `write.dbf()` that prevents writing a `tbl_df` object to a `.dbf` file.

Unfortunately, the error message is poorly written and it's therefore difficult to figure out exactly what is happening.

Here's a MWE

```
library(dplyr)
library(foreign)

d <- data_frame( x = 1:4, y = rnorm(4) )
write.dbf(d, "test.dbf")
  Error in write.dbf(d, "test.dbf") : unknown column type in data frame
```

Comment: Would `write.dbf(tbl_dt(d), "test.dbf")` work for you?

Comment: In fact, I normally get around this by using `write.dbf(as.data.frame(d), "test.dbf")`, though yours is likely faster.

Answer (score 5):

The solution here is to force the class of `d` to a bare `data.frame`

```
class(d)
 [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
df <- as.data.frame(d)
class(df)
 [1] "data.frame"
write.dbf(as.data.frame(df), "test.dbf")  # works
```

I've filed a bug report with the `foreign` people, but hopefully this post can save someone else some pain.

Comment: Funny how these things come in groups. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32286680/baffling-error-using-dataprep-function-in-r-synth-package) shows the exact same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure it's fair to assert a bug in `foreign`. Consider this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=11:20)
class(df)
# [1] "data.frame"
mode(df$x)              # as expected
# [1] "numeric"
mode(df[,"x"])          # as expected
# [1] "numeric"

dp <- data_frame(x=1:10, y=11:20)
class(dp)
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
mode(dp$x)
# [1] "numeric"         # as expected
mode(dp[,"x"])
# [1] "list"            # WTF?!
```

There are many, many functions in R that use, e.g., `mode(my.data.frame[,"mycolumn"])` to test the mode of a column in a dataframe, but with a tbl_df object, the mode returned is "list".

Comment: I guess I think the bug is not necessarily that `write.dbf()` doesn't handle all types of objects, but `dplyr` is becoming pretty widely used and the error message is inscrutable. As long as they change the error message, I'm happy with the functionality.

Comment: Well, this is a bit philosophical, but IMO the problem is with `dplyr`. The fact that a so-called "data_frame" returns "list" when the mode of a column is tested, is IMO unconscionable. It breaks code in a vast number of functions/packages.